# How can I tell how many leader points I have?

Tags: halo-wars-2

Unlike in *Halo Wars*, in Halo Wars 2, your leader powers do not come unlocked at the beginning of the game.  You need to purchase them in order to use them.  To do this, you must spend leader points on them.

How can you tell how many leader points you have?  The game doesn't really mention where you can look to find out how many you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of leader points one has is located near the mini map in the bottom right hand corner.  It has a star icon next to it, and a number that denotes how many points you have (circled in red in this screenshot):

[image: Leader Points]